# What is the g object in this Flask code?

Tags: python, flask

I found this code that times each response, but I'm not sure where `g` is supposed to come from.  What is `g`?

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
  g.start = time.time()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception=None):
    diff = time.time() - g.start
    print diff
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[`g`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.g) is an object provided by Flask. It is a global namespace for holding any data you want during a single app context. For example, a `before_request` handler could set `g.user`, which will be accessible to the route and other functions.

```
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def load_user():
    user = User.query.get(request.session.get("user_id"))
    g.user = user

@app.route("/admin")
def admin():
    if g.user is None or not g.user.is_admin:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

An app context lasts for one request / response cycle, `g` is not appropriate for storing data across requests. [Use a database, redis, the session, or another external data source for persisting data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask)

---

Note that the dev server and any web server will output timing information in the logs already.  If you really want to profile your code, you can use [the Werkzeug application profiler](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/middleware/profiler/).